# How to get a file from remote server and dispose to user as a download?

Tags: php, download, remote-access

Sorry if I did not get this title right.

I have in my server the redirect.php script that receives a URL passed by the client user, fetches the content using `file_get_contents()` function and them shows it to the user with `echo()` function.

The problem is when the user points directly to a PDF or JPG file in that URL and them the script shows the file contents as binary code.

When I set the code to recognize when the requested URL points directly to a downloadable file,

What should be the function or header to echo to the user so that his browser ask him to download the file insted of showing it?

Do I have to first put it into a file inside my server or can I do it directly from a command like `file_get_contents()`? If I can do that without writing it to my server, it would be a much better approuch.

*I can't point directly to the server because some sites are blocked by my employee and the third party company that does this service thinks that **StakExchenge** sites are malicious and not constructive and were tegged as online communities like Facebook.*

Comment: you need to TELL the user what kind of file it is. e.g. `header('Content-type: application/pdf'); echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/foo.pdf');`

Comment: @MarcB Great! Is that just that? No need to put it to my server first?

Comment: well, yeah, if you want your server to be a proxy, then this has to run on that server.

Comment: @MarcB your comment is the correct answer, you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sourcefile = "http://www.myremotewebsite.com/myfile.jpg";
$destfile = "myfile.jpg";
copy($sourcefile, $destfile);
```